# we have 2 files with jumbled headers

Tags: text-processing

There are 2 files say File1 and File2

- File1 has only Headers like

  ```
  Field2 Field1 Field3
  ```

and

- File2 has both Headers and Data too like

  ```
  Field3 Field2 Field1
  ABC    DEF    GHI
  JKL    MNO    PQRS
  ```

I have to synchronize 2 headers fields in files like

File1.txt

```
Field1 Field2 Field3
```

File2.txt

```
Field1 Field2 Field3
GHI    DEF    ABC
PQRS   MNO    JKL
```

Comment: First of all: what have you tried so far? We are not your free one-stop shop for arbitrary solutions; we're a community that can help you learn to do things yourself.

Comment: And second, why do you want to look at File1 at all if it doesn't contain any data?

Comment: The header in File1 looks incorrect. Are you sure it is: `Field2 Field1 Field3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {
        # read the first file, save the desired field order
        n = split($0, field_order)
        next
    } 
    FNR==1 {
        # read the first line of the second file
        # store the mapping of field name to existing column number
        n = split($0, header)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            current_field_order[header[i]] = i
    }
    {
        # output the fields in the desired order
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            printf "%s%s", $(current_field_order[field_order[i]]), OFS
        print ""
    }
' file1 file2
```

This will destroy the column alignment. You can pipe the output into `| column -t` to make it pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` to split the file2 to multiple corresponding files per header value, then paste them altogether with your desired order saved in file1 as header only.

```
awk 'BEGIN{getline;h1=$1;h2=$2;h3=$3}
          {print $1>h1; print $2>h2; print $3>h3}
' file2
```

Then do `paste` from header of file1.

```
paste `cat file1`
DEF     GHI     ABC
MNO     PQRS    JKL
```

if you want paste in header order (not based on header order in file1), you could do as follow.

```
paste Field{1..3}
GHI     DEF     ABC
PQRS    MNO     JKL
```